# search string value in array values recursively?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, search

new with recursive thing and i want to create search engine depend on value user typing and get it from array values all word in value that user typing

for example i have this array :

```
$array = array('it', 'pro', 'gram', 'mer', 'programmer');
$string = "itprogrammer";
```

sorry bad grammar. if anyone can help i appreciate it a lot. thanks you for your help.

Comment: Why does it need to be recursive?

Comment: I don't see how it can be recursive. Usually recursive is when the array is multidimensional, this is a flat array.

Comment: @Andreas thanks for explanation. so is it any possible or it just impossible doing it in flat array?

Comment: As I said, I don't know how to do recursive on a flat array. Maybe it's possible. But I don't see why it should be recursive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to filter out any values of the array which are not a substring of `$string`. Note I have used `stripos` for a case-insensitive search, if you want the search to be case-sensitive just use `strpos` instead.

```
$array = array('pro', 'gram', 'merit', 'program', 'it', 'programmer'); 
$string = "programit";
print_r(array_filter($array, function ($v) use($string) { return stripos($string, $v) !== false; }));
```

Output:

```
array
(
    [0] => pro
    [1] => gram
    [3] => program
    [4] => it
)
```

**Update**

Here is a recursive function which gives the same result.

```
function find_words($string, $array) {
    if (count($array) == 0) return $array;
    if (stripos($string, $array[0]) !== false)
        return array_merge(array($array[0]), find_words($string, array_slice($array, 1)));
    else
        return find_words($string, array_slice($array, 1));
}
```

Demo of both methods on [rextester](http://rextester.com/VQQA16909)

Comment: You missed " i hope is 'pro,gram,it' "

Comment: @RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi see OPs edit and please remove your downvote as this answer actually gives the correct result.

Comment: thanks sir but is it recursive way? im new with recursive thing

Comment: @IhsanDn why does it need to be recursive?

Comment: @Nick just want to know how to do it recursively sir. just learning other way

Comment: @IhsanDn this isn't really a problem that is well suited to recursion as you need to process the values in `$array` one by one.

Comment: @Nick SO said that `You last voted on this answer 15 mins ago. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited.`. Sorry for it.

Comment: can i ask you again. what if input and output like this. $string = 'programmerit'; and result is 
pro, gram, merit <br>
program, merit <br>
programmer, it

Comment: @RameshKithsiriHettiArachchi thank you. Unfortunately OPs original question wasn't accurately worded so your approach was perfectly reasonable based on the data he originally gave as the expected result.

Comment: @IhsanDn I don't understand your last comment. If "merit programmer" is in the result, then why isn't "program it", "programmer it", "pro gram merit", "pro gram it" etc.?

Comment: @IhsanDn by the way I added a recursive function to my answer based on your original data.

Comment: @Nick okay sorry nick bad explanation. i mean output is all possible words in array from user input string show in new paragraph

Comment: @IhsanDn if you want to output the values separated by `<br>` you can just `echo implode('<br>', find_words($string, $array));`

Comment: @Nick got error with recursive way. im using php 7 by the way. it said array_merge argument 2 is not array and invalid argument in implode using find_words function

Comment: @IhsanDn see my edit, i've included a link to a demo of both versions running on PHP7 on [rextester](http://rextester.com/VQQA16909).

Comment: @Nick can you see may edited question? thanks a lot master

Comment: @Nick yeah both of your answer works. i miss something sorry